# Android ProGuard Unable to access jarfile ..\lib\proguard.jar in IntelliJ 11.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I have a problem about `Unable to access jarfile ..\lib\proguard.jar` when run `Export Singed Application Package` from IntelliJ 11.1.

Environment:

- Run proguard is **success** in Android SDK r16.
- Run proguard is **failed** in Android SDK r17.

The problem is IntelliJ setting error or IntelliJ 11 bug?

Answer (score 36):

Edit `$ANDROID_SDK\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat` and set absolute path to `PROGUARD_HOME`

May look like this:

```
SET PROGUARD_HOME="c:\android-sdk\tools\proguard"
java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
```

Comment: It works now thanks, I've up-marked your answer because it is clearly explained with the full SET command. Although please change to.

SET PROGUARD_HOME= "%ANDROID_HOME%"\tools\proguard

Answer (score 20):

This issue can also come up if you have a space anywhere in your Android SDK path. The solution is to modify `$ANDROID_SDK\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.sh`. Change this last line:

```
java -jar $PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar "$@"
```

to

```
java -jar "$PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar" "$@"
```

Comment: This is what solved my issue with the default Android Studio/ProGuard setup on OSX.

Comment: while you are at it, you should modify proguardgui.sh and retrace.sh in the same directory as well

Comment: This worked, in my case when Android Studio installed, it installed as "Android Studio.app" (note the space)

Now onto more ProGuard Hell, as it can't locate references.

Comment: now it says "Error: Unable to access jarfile $PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar" . :(

Comment: 1+ I switched my eclipse from 32bit to 64bit ubuntu and faced the same issue. But the above resolved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

On Mac:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguard.sh
```

Change this last line:

```
java -jar $PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar "$@"
```

to

```
java -jar "$PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar" "$@"
```

Comment: 1+ I switched my eclipse from 32bit to 64bit ubuntu and faced the same issue. But the above resolved it. Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide your input on this post also. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32783837/1503130 Struggling for a couple of hours now.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it happened for me on my Windows machine was because I moved the location of the Android SDK in my file system but I didn't update my `PROGUARD_HOME` system variable. The `PROGUARD_HOME` system variable is referenced in the `{android-sdk}\tools\proguard\bin\project.bat` file.

***Extra Info:***

The value of my `PROGUARD_HOME` system variable was set as a path within my old Android SDK directory. I shouldn't experience this in future because I've now created an `ANDROID_HOME` system variable which points to my Android SDK and my `PROGUARD_HOME` system variable is now defined as follows:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\proguard
```

All I have to do in future if I relocate my Android SDK in future is update my `ANDROID_HOME` system variable.

Comment: Yes, seems like that's the solution, according to this issue being reported: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66733 . here's an image showing what should be done: https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=667330015000&name=proguard.png&token=6OjT81-h9UWBgIjHxn-ofzfW_E8%3A1395411984200&inline=1

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been occurred after I had updated  tools (26.6.2)+ migrating to win7 from xp.

The possible reason perhaps in proguard place because some folders can have a space in their path folders' names(like "Program Files",e.g.).
In my case i did what has been pointed above but copied the entire proguard folder to new place (mine new became "c:\proguard") and put its path to PROGUARD_HOME

```
SET PROGUARD_HOME="c:\proguard"
```

in $ANDROID_SDK\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat file.

---

Another possible way:
After tools upgrading i found very simple solution:
find environment variable
PROGARD_HOME on windows
and edit its path to
(in mine case ,currently) :

```
not  C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard
```

but  "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard"